# RxJs take first event every x seconds

Tags: angular, rxjs

I see lots of posts about lossless rate limiting, but that is not exactly what I am trying to do. I have an event that fires once with every http call in my angular 9 app, which triggers a another event that makes a separate http call. However I don't want this call to be going out constantly with every single event, I just want it to fire once like every x amount of seconds, but only when http calls actively being made. I don't care about losing the in between events. I've played around with various combinations of takeUntil, interval, and some other things but nothing really works the way I want. Was hoping you smart people would have some suggestions.

Comment: Can you post the code which you have tried?

Comment: I haven't kept any of it sorry, as none of it has worked. I'm kinda just at the stage where I'm frantically searching the interne , trying to piece together similar examples or find someone that has tried to do something similar.

Comment: Im thinking maybe exhaust/exhaustMap would be the way to go about doing this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `exhaustMap` and an artificially extended inner observable. We can artificially extend a call by merging it with a silent timer. That way the inner observable only completes when the last of the merged observables complete. In the meantime, values from the `source$` are ignored.

In this example, we stop ignoring the source$ every 10 seconds (unless the inner observable takes longer, then we keep waiting).

That might look like this:

```js
const tenSeconds = 10000;

// source$ emits when http calls being made
source$.pipe(
  exhaustMap(_ => merge(
    separateHttpCall(),
    timer(tenSeconds).pipe(
      filter(_ => false)
    )
  ))
)
```

Comment: This works pretty well, and is actually pretty close to where I was starting ending up. I was trying to use delay to do it, but this makes much more sense in hindsight. Thank you!